# How to check application context in Typo3 9?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'd like to switch between Production and Development application context. Where in backend [BE] is possbile to check current application context and eventually switch it? In former versions of Typo3 it was possible in Installation Module. Please beginner friendly answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For retrieving the Application Context you can use the getApplicationContext function from the GeneralUtility:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext()
```

You can check which ApplicationContext is used with these functions:

```
$applicationContext = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext();
$applicationContext->isDevelopment();
$applicationContext->isTesting();
$applicationContext->isProduction();
```

Alternatively you can use `getenv('TYPO3_CONTEXT')` to retrieve the ApplicationContext string(which maybe doesn't exist if not set anywhere else which is why I'd recommend using the ApplicationContext functions from the GeneralUtility).

You can also check in the TYPO3 Backend by checking the PHP Info in the Environment module in the Admin Tools where you should find the category `Environment`.

The default Application Context if not set by anything else is `Production`.

You can change it either in a .env file with `TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development` and loading it with for example with the composer package helhum/dotenv-connector or by setting it in the .htaccess file with `SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development`. It is even possible to define it in the system but the most common method is via the `.env` or the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2):

There's an environment variable that TYPO3 listens on to switch it's own context. It should be set in something like the `.htaccess` file: `SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development`

If it is set, you can access it with `getenv(TYPO3_CONTEXT)` in php.

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is no variable like that after checking with php code and in server configuration. So what is default value of this variable in Typo3? Can we check it in the BE?

Comment: Environment variables are not sensitive to backend or frontend and should be set by the environment, which is not part of your typo3 instance. I usually set it in the default webserver configuration as those differ in my case. Im not sure about the default value though

Answer (score 2):

Also I've found what i was looking for in the BE:

[image]